# iOS: Calendar reminder night before for early meeting

Tags: ios, calendar, reminders

Is it possible to receive a reminder for a meeting that is early the next morning (ideally "early" would be user defined option).  Do any any 3rd party iOS apps support this?

I've had times where an early meeting was scheduled weeks ahead of time, but by the time that morning came, I'd forgotten about it and not adjusted my wake up time.

Comment: You mean something different than using "alert" and "second alert"?  Typically when I have this situation, I make one of the alerts for 12 hours.

Comment: I'm looking for something that will automatically create an alert the night before if there's an early calendar entry the next morning.